# Who was the oldest actor to play a teenager?

Tags: trope

There's a common trope in Hollywood where [teenagers are played by adult actors](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DawsonCasting). But which TV show or movie set the absolute record in terms of the age difference between the role and the actor? To clarify:

- The character played must be a teenager, so younger than 20 years old
- The portrayal is done in a serious manner - not as a parody, or a "what if" clip, or a dream, etc
- It must be a live action film or a TV show

Comment: Too lazy to look it up, but Alan Ruck was ancient when he played Ferris Beuller's friend Cameron in Ferris Beuller's Day Off.  Probably was pushing 30 at that point.

Comment: Not sure about it, but I think there is a difference between casting an older actor to only play a teenager (which the trope is mostly about) and casting him to play a role at multiple ages (including the age of the actor). Answers here include examples for both. First case: [Moaning Myrtle](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/75545/11182) and [Ferris Bueller's Day Off](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/75538/11182), second case: [Dangal](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/75556/11182) and [The Natural](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/75540/11182)

Comment: ["How do you do, fellow kids?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7lNBMGmGF0) :)

Comment: Think this gets much worse if you have a movie where there are multiple sequels with very little time passing in the movies, but a lot of time passing for the actors playing them.

Comment: wet hot american summer: first day of camp might be up there

Comment: @problemofficer ahahah I was expecting that!

Comment: (Not an exact fit, as this is college and not teenaged.  Although the agre difference may be greater than many of the other examples mentioned.  Besides, even if this would be technically compliant, this does violate at least the spirit of the second bullet point.)  Patrick Stewart played a college student in an episode called Tapestry.  [Youtube video segment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXefQxyMj_A)

Comment: Check out the 1935Will  Hay film "Boy's Will be Boys", there are some suspicious looking teenagers there. One of the boys appears to be balding? Check out here: https://youtu.be/bV4s0RJlLoE?list=PLLyOEC1TBK-5brJPQo3-2aw3kZYab3J42&t=1563

Comment: Alternatively: "Moore Marriott as a Stableboy (uncredited)" in the 1935 Will Hay film, "Dandy Dick". given that Marriot was born in 1895, this would make him 39-40.

Comment: Just remembered: "James Robinson Clitheroe (24 December 1921 – 6 June 1973), popularly known as Jimmy Clitheroe, was an English comic entertainer. He is best remembered for his BBC Radio programme, The Clitheroe Kid (1956-72), a version of which was produced for television on the ITV network under the title Just Jimmy (1964-68)." This would make him around 47 years old at the end of his TV show while around 51 at the end of his radio show.

Comment: I guess El Chavo del Ocho could be considered a parody (although I would consider it comedy more than parody) but Chespirito was already in his 50s and playing a school boy.

Comment: Michael J. Pollard, born 1939, played Jahn in a 1966 episode of _Star Trek_ entitled "Miri."  Age 27 isn't as big a stretch for playing a teenager as others listed here, but in the story, Jahn is not just a teen, but a pre-adolescent.  The story involves a planet of children infected with a virus that kills them when they reach puberty.  But the virus also causes them to age very slowly, so while Jahn is physiologically still a child, he's a very old one.

Comment: @problemofficer You should make that an answer. Steve was 51 when that episode was filmed and released, and he was portraying someone who was (we'll say) 18. That's a 33 year difference!

Comment: By the way, I don't think counts as a "trope."  Casting adults as teenagers is commonly done for practical reasons rather than thematic ones.

Comment: I would also exclude flashbacks and CGI overlays, otherwise I'd say Carrie Fisher at age 60 playing Leia in Rogue One as a 19 year old. (41 year gap)

Comment: @Monso - I'm not sure that would count anyway. I don't think Fisher was actually involved with the production of Rogue One. She only said one word - "hope" - and I'm pretty sure that was just a soundbite from the originals. A better example would be Jeff Bridges in Tron Legacy, but in that case it was more like a 65-year-old playing a 30-year-old.

Comment: Major CGI composition or de-aging violates the spirit of the question. That should be edited in as a rule IMO.

Comment: How has Elijah Wood never played a teenager??

Comment: Not necessarily a teenager, but Jack Benny at 47 played an Oxford undergrad in *Charley's Aunt* (1941).

Comment: Ingrid Bergman was 33 when cast as the 14 year old Joan of Arc and Henry Winkler was 29 at the start of Happy Days and 40 at the series conclusion.

Comment: Related: [Why do older actors play teenage roles?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/118186/1006)

Comment: As Adrian McCarthy said, I don't think this is a "trope". My understanding is that "trope" refers to things in-universe.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

[Aamir Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aamir_Khan) was **51 when he played the role of a 19 year old boy** in [*Dangal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangal_(film)).

From [Bollywood Life article](http://www.bollywoodlife.com/news-gossip/dangal-pk-3-idiots-the-changing-face-of-aamir-khan-in-bollywood)

> So Aamir Khan has done it again what he does the best. The PK actor has gone through a drastic makeover for his upcoming film, Dangal, in which he will be seen going through three different stages for **he will play the role of a 19-year-old, 29-year-old and 55-year-old.**

Below is the image of him as 19 years old.

[image]

Another example, [Amitabh Bachchan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amitabh_Bachchan) was **67 years old when he played the role of a 12 year old boy** suffering from a rare genetic disorder called [progeria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progeria) in *[Paa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paa_(film))*.

From [Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paa_(film)),

> Auro (Amitabh Bachchan) is an intelligent and witty 12-year-old boy with an extremely rare genetic disorder called progeria. Mentally he is twelve and very normal, but physically he looks five times older.

Though, in this case, the character he played was supposed to look like an old man.

Comment: Fun fact: his star son Abhishek Bachchan played the role of Auro's father.

Comment: The Amitabh Bachchan example doesn’t seem in the spirit of the question, since the child there is *supposed* to look like an old man, not a child.  But the Aamir Khan example seems perfect.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine That's why I kept both.

Comment: that's a "boy"?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai - I must admit that he looks far younger than 51, at least.

Comment: I looked just like that when I was 19. Except for all the muscles.  And the tan. And the movie-star good looks. I had acne and a mullet ... I looked nothing like that.

Comment: Worth noting: Aamir Khan played mostly the latter two ages in the film; his screen time as a 19-year old is, as far as I can tell, less than a minute. (Perhaps also worth noting? _Dangal_'s [surprising performance in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_highest-grossing_films_in_China&oldid=788823695) has made it the highest-grossing Indian film so far, and it is currently [available on Netflix](https://www.netflix.com/title/80166185) at least in the US.)

Comment: *Paa* is reminiscent of [*Jack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_(1996_film)), in which a 45-year-old Robin Williams played a 10-year-old boy with [Werner syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_syndrome).

Comment: This was basically a flashback and shouldn't count.

Comment: [Congratulations, for the 2nd runner up Rewards for the 2nd quarter of 2017](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2888/1190)

Comment: @A J 9 Another Aamir Khan example is for *3 Idiots*(2009) where his character is in college so about seventeen - eighteen years old, when he himself was forty four years old.

Answer (score 60):

[Shirley Henderson](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Shirley_Henderson) was around 37 when she played Moaning Myrtle in the Harry Potter movies.  Born 1965, appeared in [Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0295297/) which came out in 2002 and [Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0330373/) which came out in 2005.

Comment: Might be worth noting that Moaning Myrtle's (corporeal) age is 14 (while the sum of her corporeal and ghost age is around 63)

Comment: @GhotiandChips and the average of her corporeal and total (including ghost) age is around 37.

Answer (score 44):

Stockard Channing (born 1944) played teenager Rizzo in Grease (1978) at the age of 34.

[image]

Comment: That is significantly younger than the existing answers.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I don't agree that some of the existing answers are valid - some involve heavy makeup and are stories that cover large time frames so the actor plays a range of ages.  I also think that roles where the teenager has a disease shouldn't count.

Comment: Yes and that's not all. Grease had a ridiculous amount of people in their 30s and late 20s playing teenagers, and it showed. Olivia Newton-John (1948), Michael Tucci (1946), Jamie Donnelly (1947), Dennis Steward (1947) and probably many more. Were teenagers forbidden in films back then?

Comment: @mattboy, back in those days there was a lot less industry around acting to support and train young actors and actresses.  So there were a lot fewer GOOD teen actors working.

Comment: @mattboy I think Grease was intended as a showcase for the stars.

Comment: Jack Benny was about 47 when he played an Oxford undergrad in _Charley's Aunt_ (1941).

Comment: @Wildcard Not to mention that it was a *musical* - they needed good actors who were also great singers. Olivia herself was "concerned that she was too old to play a high school senior", and I suspect a lot of the other actors had similar feelings about themselves. Nowadays, teens played by *actual* teens look weird :D

Comment: @Luaan - I know, right? When I saw Tom Holland playing Peter Parker, I thought he looked like a toddler.

Comment: Tell me more, tell me more...

Comment: @Gallifreyan And yet it was infinitely more interesting and accessible to a larger audience.

Answer (score 28):

**Ferris Bueller's sidekick Cameron was played by 29-year-old Alan Ruck in *Ferris Bueller's Day Off*.**

Alan Ruck was born in 1956, and appeared as Ferris Bueller's trusty high-school friend Cameron in the 1986 movie *Ferris Bueller's Day Off*.  Mr. Ruck was probably not 30 during filming, since movies are always shot months or even years before they are released.

*Thanks to Joe for the comment on the original question that led to this answer.

(**Fun fact:** I've bumped into Alan Ruck twice in my grocery store in Studio City, CA. He even said "hi" once because he could see how star-struck I was.)

[image]

Answer (score 28):

[Robert Redford](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000602/) was 48 when [The Natural](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087781) was released. Granted he played a 35 y/o for most of the movie, but he plays a [19 y/o pitcher on a way to a tryout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Natural_(film)#plot) in the prologue.

Answer (score 18):

There is a very popular Mexican comedy TV show named "[El Chavo del Ocho](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0229889/)" (1972-1979), in which all the characters are played by adults even when they are playing children's roles.

I understand that some people may consider it a parody, but truly it is not. It may be actors portraying children, but they are not parodying them: within the El Chavo's universe they are not pretending to be children, they *are* children.

[image]

[Roberto Gómez Bolaños (aka Chespirito)](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0350867/) was the creator/writer/producer/director of the show, and he also played El Chavo, an 8-year-old boy who escaped from an orphanage and lives in the apartment #8.

Chespirito was born in 1929, and the show concluded in 1979. So in the last season, he was an 50-year-old man portraying an 8-year-old boy (42 years difference).

[image]

Comment: actually he lived in a barrel under the appartment 8, but I think you are in the spirit of the question.

Comment: kind off true until the serie was moved to another Mexican tv channel..., I remember many episodes where ***la Chilindrina*** was about to tell where ***El Chavo*** lives, but she was always interrupted by ***Kiko*** LOL

Comment: I want to add my two cents about this. This show is golden, and I regularly watch it. Let me tell you, with this actors, you forget that they're adults playing children. You can really think they're children. It's amazing. It's a shame there aren't much episodes subtitled in English.

Comment: I would definitely argue that casting obvious adults as children counts as parody. The genre of the SHOW may not be parody, but the nature of the casting IS. I don't care how good the acting is... nobody is going to take Morgan Freeman playing a 12-year-old seriously.

Comment: An 8-year-old is not a teenager.

Comment: It's not all that uncommon to have adults who are clearly not children/teenagers portray much younger characters for artistic reasons, e.g. the British TV play Blue Remembered Hills, but that doesn't seem in the spirit of this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Remembered_Hills

Comment: There is similar idea going with the current Hulu TV Series, Pen15.

Answer (score 14):

Here's one from Japan: The lead role in [My Love Story!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Love_Story!_(2015_film)), a major production from a major studio, was played by [Ryohei Suzuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryohei_Suzuki). The character is 15 years old throughout (no flashbacks or early life scene setting), but at that time Suzuki was 32 years old, so a 17 year difference.

(I've also just thought - The Curious Case of Benjamin Button: Brad Pitt was 44 when he played BB at 12 years old - I can't remember if he appeared at an *earlier* age, though)

Comment: Pitt was one of my first thoughts, too. Although 12 is not a teenager :)

Answer (score 11):

*Wet, Hot American Summer* (the Netflix show not the film) had *multiple* actors in their 40's and early 50's portraying teenage and early 20's characters.

Granted this was part of the joke, but for your question this should work (unless you would qualify this as parody).

For example, Michael Showalter was 45 when the series was filmed.   And he has confirmed they are indeed teens [here](http://m.eonline.com/news/659326/wet-hot-american-summer-cast-is-ageless-seriously-look-at-these-first-day-of-camp-pics):

> "We thought it was funny that in the original we played a bunch of thirty year olds playing teenagers. Now we're in our forties and our characters are even younger," Showalter said in a statement.

If not the show, then the movie, which was not done to the absurd level as the show would still count.

Comment: *Blue Remembered Hills* is a similar case, in that the children being played by adults was for effect and the oldest of the actors was 45 at the time. I don't know if the character he played had reached the age of 13 yet though.

Comment: That's the very definition of parody: exaggerated imitation.

Answer (score 9):

Although he is not the oldest in these answers, he is playing a fairly younger role in *Hannah Montana*. **Jason Earles** plays his role as a 15 years old kid, and can you believe he was on his 30s?

[image]

Comment: Random down votes?

Answer (score 7):

This example will be very hard to beat for anyone who cares about historical accuracy.

In the 10 May 1980 episode of *Fantasy Island* **My Fair Pharaoh/The Power** the "My Fair Pharaoh" part had the protagonist going back in time to meet her hero Queen of Kings Cleopatra VII Philopator.  Cleopatra's brother and enemy King Ptolemy XIII Theos Philopator (62/61 BC to 47 BC) was portrayed by Michael Ansara (born 15 April 1922, died 31 July 2013) who was thus aged 58 years and 25 days when the episode aired and was probably 43 or 44 years older than Ptolemy and 3.8 to 4.07 times as old as Ptolemy when filming his scenes.

This is an example of a middle aged man portraying a character arbitrarily depicted as an adult despite being one of the most famous child rulers in history!

So this could be the extreme example depending on whether you go by Ptolemy's historical age or his unspecified adult fictional age in the episode.

Comment: So, was he portraying Ptolemy XIII as he was before he died?  I forget how Fantasy Island worked.  Ptolemy died at 15 years of age, so was the portrayal of Ptolemy before or up to that age?

Comment: Is [this account](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/53112/m-a-golding) also yours? [Refer here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge them and have a better control on all your posts.

Comment: This answer is confusing.  I think you're saying that the adult actor was playing a character who was, in the film universe, an adult—but the character was a historical figure who was, in actual history at the time in which the film was set, a teenager.  But that's not in the spirit of the question at all.

Answer (score 4):

Though he also appears as an elderly version of the character in the framing story at the beginning and end of the film, (then) **40-year-old Martin Short played a 10-year-old** in [*Clifford*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109447/).  The film was a comedy, and the casting of an adult actor in the role of a young child was surely intended to be humorous, but it's never specifically highlighted as a joke in the film--it's played more or less straight.

Answer (score 4):

**[Nicola Coughlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicola_Coughlan)** (born 9 January 1987) plays **Clare Devlin** in [Derry Girls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derry_Girls) (2018-2022).

[image: Nicola Coughlan][image: Clare Devlin]

This means that Coughlan has played a school-age child while aged at least 34 years by the release of the series finale. The cast members of *Derry Girls* playing schoolchildren are mostly in their late twenties, but Coughlan is the eldest in real life.

Answer (score 3):

If we take the premise of the movie *The Curious Case of Benjamin Button*, then Brad Pitt born 1963 played a teenager in 2008 at some point or another in that movie.

Answer (score 1):

Bruno S. (born 1932) played Kaspar Hauser in The Enigma of Kaspar Hauser (1974).  Hauser's age isn't directly mentioned in the film although he is referred to as a young man, but Hauser was a historical figure and the film tells the story of his life from when he arrived in Nuremberg aged 16 until his death aged 21.  Bruno S was 41 at the time of filming.

Answer (score 0):

Jack Benny at 47 played an Oxford undergraduate – maybe under 20, maybe not – in *[Charley's Aunt](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0033457/)* (1941).

In the same show, Laird Cregar (27) played father to James Ellison (31).  I wonder what is the record for a parent younger than their child.  In *[The Magicians](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4254242)*, Mageina Tovah as Zelda is 14 years younger than Marlee Matlin as her daughter Harriet (as another character comments; Zelda lives in a more magical environment).