# Why do older actors play teenage roles?

Tags: casting, the-amazing-spider-man, spider-man, child-actors

In many films, I have seen that a lot of teenage characters are played by actors in their 20's.

Two notable examples are:

- In *Spider-Man*, Tobey Maguire (26) plays an 18-year-old.
- In *The Amazing Spider-Man*, Andrew Garfield (27) plays a 17-year-old.

Why were older performers cast in these roles? Were *actual* teenagers deemed unworthy?

Comment: Do you feel like this has happened less since 2010? [Kaitlyn Dever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaitlyn_Dever) was 21 when she played a high-school senior (which I guess means 18?) in _Booksmart (2019)_.

Comment: Your question might generally be pointing to a genuine issue worth asking about, but it's really not bringing it across particularly well, which might be causing the downvotes that the topic itself might not actually deserve. First, calling films before 2010 "older films" just makes no sense, no matter how old you are. That's simply not how the world works. Maybe just leaving away the film age factor would work better, since this is a timeless issue, as Paul points out in his comment...

Comment: ...Then you also say the "majority" of films do that and you name...two Spider-Man films, which is a somewhat confined set of examples. This might lead people to believe you're just imagining things based on a very limited experience. Again, you're probably pointing to a genuine trend (or rather a timeless issue), but it's really not expressed all that appropriately.

Comment: @Kyralessa The question has already been adapted for the irrelevance of the film's age.

Comment: Related: [Who was the oldest actor to play a teenager?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/75534/1006)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There can be various reasons such as dealing with adults is more manageable than with teenagers, child labor law, guardian interface, etc.

> Marcia Ross — who cast 10 Things I Hate About You and Clueless — explains, in most cases, “actors under the age of 18 need to have guardians on set and work a limited set of hours because of schooling.” So, casting older actors becomes more of a financial and production decision. Though, for both of those films, she clarifies that there was no mandate about what age the actors should be. - [teenvogue](https://www.teenvogue.com/story/problem-teen-characters-played-by-adults)

Also, you can find more adult-trained actors who can be easier to work with rather than inexperienced teenagers who might.

Also, teenagers go through changes more drastically in less time interval

> “They do tend to grow up a lot,” he told us at a charity party in North London. “In one film they were children but when I saw them again they were teenagers. Now they are adults. I still talk to them as if they were children and I have to stop myself.” - Jason (From [Express](https://www.express.co.uk/dayandnight/99921/Potter-cast-growing-up-too-fast-for-Jason))

Adults, on the other hand, have more experiences, have fewer bodily changes, and no worry about the limitation of child labor.

It's a common trope and called [Dawson Casting](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DawsonCasting)